# PL/SQL: Center query RESULTS

Tags: oracle, formatting, sqlplus

I've googled all I know how to Google. I need some new eyes to look at this.

I am trying to center the RESULTS of a query.  Here is what I have so far ...

```
    set lines 2000 pages 2000
    COLUMN total HEADING "Total" FORMAT A20 JUSTIFY CENTER
    COLUMN sending_fi HEADING "Sending M" FORMAT A20 JUSTIFY CENTER
    COLUMN receiving_fi HEADING "Receiving M" FORMAT A20 JUSTIFY CENTER
    COLUMN status HEADING "Payment Status" FORMAT A20 JUSTIFY CENTER
    SET UNDERLINE =
    select
        count(*) as "Total",
        p.sending_fi,
        p.receiving_fi,
        p.status
    from
        my_schema.my_table p
    where
        p.match_date
            between
                to_date
                    (
                        '2017/10/26:00:00:00',
                        'yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss'
                    )
            and
                to_date
                    (
                        '2017/10/28:23:59:59',
                        'yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss'
                    )
    and
        p.expedited='1'
    and
        p.status='DELIVERED'
    group by
        p.sending_fi,
        p.receiving_fi,
        p.status
    order by
        1
        DESC
    ;
```

Which produces this output ...

`Total              Sending M           Receiving M         Payment Status

==================== ==================== ==================== =================
              266759 BAC                  BAC                  DELIVERED

               49954 JPM                  BAC                  DELIVERED

               45194 BAC                  JPM                  DELIVERED

               25990 WFC                  BAC                  DELIVERED

               25676 JPM                  WFC                  DELIVERED

               24120 WFC                  JPM                  DELIVERED

               23565 BAC                  WFC                  DELIVERED`

The COLUMN HEADERS (names) are centered, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to center the results.

I'm a non-privileged user (all i ever really do are select update and insert), with very limited SQL skills. Please be gentle in your suggestions.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL. SQL merely gets you the data. Whether column data is left, right or center aligned is a matter of the tool you are using to select the data. Same for the font style and color. As long as you work with a developer tool such as Toad, SQL Developer or sql plus, you shouldn't give such things any thought. Once you write a program for users though, you want the data to look pretty. So no matter whether you are using PHP/HTML or C# or whatever, tell your grid/table to center align the data.

Comment: I suppose this is about sqlplus reports, which I never use. Have you tried `COLUMN sending_fi FORMAT A20 JUSTIFY CENTER`? I'll edit the tags, so you may get better help.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - `justify` controls only the headers (the OP already had that in the script, which is why his headers were already centered!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally I wrote this as a Comment. Then I thought of closing the question as a duplicate; but the only duplicate I found has no answers: just a Comment saying the same thing. (I should know, it was my Comment then, too!)

[Column Formatting JUSTIFY not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323431/column-formatting-justify-not-working)

**ANSWER**:

It looks like you want an answer in SQL*Plus. **There is no answer**. Strings and dates are always aligned to the left side of the column, and numbers to the right. Period. You can't change that (other than by adding to the strings themselves, in the query - by padding with spaces; a complete waste of time!) If you need to generate "good looking" reports, and what is available in SQL*Plus is not good enough, you must use a reporting tool; can't be done in SQL*Plus.

There seems to be some confusion about the SQL command COLUMN ... FORMAT ... JUSTIFY. Here is what the manual says:

**JUS[TIFY] {L[EFT] | C[ENTER] | R[IGHT]}**

Aligns **the heading**. If you do not use a JUSTIFY clause, headings for NUMBER columns default to RIGHT and headings for other column types default to LEFT.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12013.htm#BACHCABF

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use LPAD.

Here is a quick example:

```
COLUMN blks HEADING "Num Blocks" FORMAT A10 JUSTIFY CENTER

select 
lpad(to_char(blocks),(10-length(to_char(blocks)))/2+length(to_char(blocks)),' ') blks 
from user_segments
where rownum < 11;
```

The idea is to pad the column on the left with half of the difference between the format size and the size of the column value in spaces.

Output:

```
Num Blocks
----------
    16
    16
    16
    16
    16
    16
    16
    16
    16
    16

10 rows selected.
```

Bobby

Answer (score 0):

Bobby's answer will work for text output. You can also make use of the HTML markup feature of sqlplus and produce formatted html output. An example which extends https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_seven.htm#SQPUG531 would be

```
create table t1 (
id number
, dt date 
, vc varchar2(20) 
, constraint pk_t1 primary key (id) );

begin     
for i in 1..10 loop
 insert into t1 values (i,sysdate + i , 'Row '||i);
end loop;
commit;
end;
/

SET MARKUP HTML ON PREFORMAT OFF ENTMAP ON -
HEAD "<TITLE>Department Report</TITLE> -
<STYLE type='text/css'> -
<!-- BODY {background: #FFFFC6} --> -
<!-- TD { text-align: center} --> -
</STYLE>" -
BODY "TEXT='#FF00Ff'" -
TABLE "WIDTH='90%' BORDER='5'"
```

Then run

```
spool t.html
```

followed by your query and then

```
host firefox t.html
```